# PostgreSQL. INNER JOIN doesn't exclude anything and gives the whole table

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

Here is the 'tasks' table:

```
+----+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| id | task                   | subtask_1 | subtask_2 | subtask_3 | active_subtask |
+----+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 1  | Earn 1 million dollars | Earn 100k | Earn 500k | Earn 1m   | 3              |
+----+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 2  | Earn 2 million dollars | Earn 1m   | Earn 1.5m | Earn 2m   | 1              |
+----+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 3  | Earn 3 million dollars | Earn 2m   | Earn 2.5m | Earn 3m   | 2              |
+----+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| 4  | ...                    | ...       | ...       | ...       | ...            |
+----+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

I have 2 queries that I want to join to get a list of tasks that have non-unique active subtasks.
The first one gives me an active subtask for every task (with some 'where' conditions):

```
+----+-----------+
| id | subtask   |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Earn 1m   |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | Earn 1m   |
+----+-----------+
| 3  | Earn 2.5m |
+----+-----------+
| .  | ...       |
+----+-----------+
```

The second one gives me a list of all the non-unique active subtasks (i.e. there are more than 1 task has this active subtask):

```
+---------+
| subtask |
+---------+
| Earn 1m |
+---------+
| ...     |
+---------+
```

And here I'm trying to use INNER JOIN to get all tasks that have non-unique active subtasks.
The intended result is:

```
+----+---------+
| id | subtask |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Earn 1m |
+----+---------+
| 2  | Earn 1m |
+----+---------+
| .  | ...     |
+----+---------+
```

But I always get the full results of the first query.

The simplified SQL query (without 'where' clauses) looks like this:

```
SELECT id, 
CASE WHEN active_subtask = 1 THEN subtask_1 WHEN active_subtask = 2 THEN subtask_2 WHEN active_subtask = 3 THEN subtask_3 END 
AS subtask 
FROM "tasks" 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT CASE WHEN active_subtask = 1 THEN subtask_1 WHEN active_subtask = 2 THEN subtask_2 WHEN active_subtask = 3 THEN subtask_3 END 
 AS subtask 
 FROM "tasks" 
 GROUP BY subtask 
 HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)) AS agg 
 ON subtask = agg.subtask
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is a "non-unique active task"?

Comment: It means tasks that have non-unique active subtasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your question as *"what different tasks have the same active subtasks?"* If I got that right, here is one way..

```
with cte (id, subtask) as

(select id, split_part(concat_ws('|',subtask_1,subtask_2,subtask_3),'|', active_subtask)
from t)
 
select a.*
from cte a
join cte b on a.subtask = b.subtask and a.id <> b.id;
```

**[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wfvVp7R1B9UcpvU78uv9gz/0)**

This aproach is a little hacky so make sure to take care of `nulls` and that `|` delimiter isn't already part of your data.

---

Another alternative would be

```
with cte (id, subtask) as
(select id, 
       case when active_subtask=1 then subtask_1
            when active_subtask=2 then subtask_2
            when active_subtask=3 then subtask_3 end    
 from tasks)

select * 
from cte
where subtask in (select subtask 
                  from cte 
                  group by subtask 
                  having count(distinct id)>1);
```

**[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6qqUPMbRgg2os1SjFnS4Ef/1)**

Comment: Thank you, Phil. It works for the specified data scope, but, unfortunately, subtasks can be `null` and can contain the `|` char.

Comment: @Ivan Getting around nulls is pretty doable with `coalesce`, you just have to use a delimiter that you think is foolproof for your data. Delimiter doesn't have to be a single character. I understand if your use case is more complex than what I gathered https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wfvVp7R1B9UcpvU78uv9gz/2

Comment: In fact, any symbol I'm using as a delimiter can be a part of 'subtask' string...

Comment: @Iav Try the other alternative I added above

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach:

```
/* non-unique subtasks */
select
    id, task, subtask
from (
      select
          id, task, subtask, count(*) over(partition by subtask) c
      from (
              select id , task, subtask_1 as subtask from tasks where subtask_1 is not null union all
              select id , task, subtask_2 as subtask from tasks where subtask_2 is not null union all
              select id , task, subtask_3 as subtask from tasks where subtask_3 is not null
           ) fddl
   ) derived
where c > 1
;

/* unique subtasks */
select
    id, task, subtask
from (
      select
          id, task, subtask, count(*) over(partition by subtask) c
      from (
              select id , task, subtask_1 as subtask from tasks where subtask_1 is not null union all
              select id , task, subtask_2 as subtask from tasks where subtask_2 is not null union all
              select id , task, subtask_3 as subtask from tasks where subtask_3 is not null
           ) fddl
   ) derived
where c = 1
;
```

The essential problem here is that you have a non-normalised data structure which limits your ability to query simply. It would be better in my view to hold subtasks in a separate table to support the many-to-one relationship to the tasks table. In effect that's what the unioning subquery seen above "sort of" simulates.

Comment: I can't get any results for tasks with non-unique subtasks: [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6qqUPMbRgg2os1SjFnS4Ef/0)

Comment: apologies, **I have changed my approach** as it should not have used `group by id, task subtask` which would never match subtasks across ids, see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cr5twKesQMX9A9RjvK7QVw/0